# CSS :valid selector - Validity of two elements by using one button CSS ONLY

Tags: css

I have 2 inputs (for email and phone) and a button. I want to use rule for button only if input[type="tel"]:valid and input[type="email"]:valid at the same time, but I can't do it correctly. Is there a way of doing this using css?

Comment: what is rool for button mean?

Comment: Please include your code (html and css) in your question.

Comment: If these answers helped you, accept one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
input[type='tel']:valid ~ input[type='email']:valid ~ button {
  color: green; 
}
```

This assumes that the two input fields and the button are direct siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. However I try to answer

CSS:
:valid selector is normally on a input element where the user types data and if its a valid type it shows the css style for :valid and css style for :invalid if invalid.

```
input[type="tel"]:invalid, input[type="email"]:invalid { 
    border: 2px solid red;
}

input[type="tel"]:valid, input[type="email"]:valid { 
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

The button is normally used to submit the form. If the inputs are part of form element than the browsers validates the form before submission. You can also use javascript to validate the form before submission by adding onsubmit="return validateForm()".

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="post" **onsubmit="return validateForm()"**>
  <input type="tel" name="telephone" required>
  <input type="email" name="email" required>
  <input type="submit" value="button">
</form>
```